# Computing time and results

Tags: r

I'm running some code in R and I want to report computation time and results of the chunk of code I'm running. Since the computation take a while, I was wondering if there is a way to have as output (at the same time) the computing time and the results, without having to run the code twice (and therefore spending twice the time needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
elapsed.time <- system.time(
 results <- your.function()
)

print(elapsed.time)
print(results)
```